# How do you move custom fields to custom taxonomies using WP Queries

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

To save complication I have imported a custom fields (categories & terms) to the wp_postmeta table, which are linked to respective posts. Shown as listed in wp_postmeta:

```
meta_id post_id meta_key                meta_value
183     45      job_listing_region      Kingston
208     46      job_listing_region      Fajardo
233     47      job_listing_region      Letchworth
258     48      job_listing_region      Oxford
283     49      job_listing_region      Beaulieu-sur-Mer
```

Using a SQL query how do you move these to taxonomies & terms to the following tables?

```
wp_term_relationships
wp_term_taxonomys
wp_terms
```

I'm finding the table relationship a little confusing, whether to JOIN or UPDATE in this instance. A good reference article below for someone who knows what they're doing. Thanks in advance, Murray

[SQL to update custom post taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139221/sql-to-update-custom-post-taxonomies)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using WordPress function calls to set up your terms, instead of SQL. This is assuming you've already [registered](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) a custom taxonomy called job_listing_region.

```
// Add this to your theme's functions.php
function convert_meta_to_term() {
  global $wpdb;
  $meta_query = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'job_listing_region'
  ");
  foreach ($meta_query as $meta) {
    // Append new terms for each post
    wp_set_object_terms($meta->post_id, $meta->meta_value, 'job_listing_region', true);
  }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_convert_meta_to_term', 'convert_meta_to_term');
```

Now you can call this function by going to the URL `http://your-blog.tld/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=convert_meta_to_term`.

Comment: Thanks Dan, can you give me a heads up on how to use function calls, as I have never used them before.

Comment: Sure, I've changed the example to be callable via an [WP AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)-style request.

Comment: The error return value is `0`, have add in `AND post_type = 'job_listing'` and have checked the custom taxonomy to be `register_taxonomy( 'job_listing_region' ` still with no change to error value. Thanks again but still not sure.

Comment: Yeah, the return value `0` is totally normal. The thing you should be checking for is whether these terms are getting created, or if there are errors logged, etc. When you say you added that `AND` clause, did you also join on the `wp_posts` table? Because `wp_postmeta` has no `post_type` column. And you can call `exit` if you want to suppress the `0`. I normally do that and add some debug text in there.

Comment: Sorry I have checked for terms and log but am unable to find a solution.

Comment: I would add something like `echo "test";` to see if the function is getting called, and then I would check the result of each line to see if it's doing what you'd expect it to. Good luck!