# Update Custom Post Type Taxonomies with SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update post category but i keep error messages. I have built an update form. each category is a different product type (and a custom post).
all the other fields are working except the category

I use [this wonderful guide](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139221/sql-to-update-custom-post-taxonomies) .

I set the first query to join the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p ON tr.object_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'ye_product' AND tt.taxonomy = 'category';
```

and sure enough i get the table.

step two was to update the table

and my code is

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET term_taxonomy_id = $cat_id WHERE object_id= $post_id;
```

All i get is the error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'object_id' in 'where clause'

but I can see it. the object id is right there.

Why am I getting this error? What I did or what I didn't know I shouldn't do and did it any way?

Comment: The column `object_id` belongs in the [`wp_term_relationships` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_term_relationships).

Comment: aaaa .thank you

Comment: @SallyCJ That would make a good answer with explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error?

Because the table `wp_term_taxonomy` does not have the column `object_id`.

And the correct table that you should update is the `wp_term_relationships` table which does have the column `object_id`. See the [WordPress database diagram](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/25/WP4.4.2-ERD.png) and also the [WordPress database description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for more details.

So your SQL query should be:

```sql
UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = $cat_id WHERE object_id = $post_id;
```

**And it could work, but then:**

First, the query would *affect all rows* where the `object_id` is the value of the `$post_id`. E.g. When `$cat_id = 1` and `$post_id = 2`:

```
|------------------------------|------------------------------|
|         Before Update        |         After Update         |
|------------------|-----------|------------------|-----------|
| term_taxonomy_id | object_id | term_taxonomy_id | object_id |
|------------------|-----------|------------------|-----------|
| 10               | 2         | 1                | 2         |
| 11               | 2         | 1                | 2         |
| 35               | 2         | 1                | 2         |
```

Secondly, you would also need to *update the `count` column* in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table for rows where `term_taxonomy_id` is in the above list (`10`, `11`, `35` and `1`) — e.g. `count - 1` for `10`, `11` and `35` (i.e. the old categories).

### A Better Solution

Instead of messing with custom SQL, you should just use the WordPress term/category APIs like [`wp_set_post_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/) or [`wp_set_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/) which you can use to easily update the post categories — the later function should be used with custom taxonomies. So:

```php
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $cat_id );       // Set $cat_id as the only category
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $cat_id, true ); // Or add $cat_id to the existing list
```

### Additional Notes

- You really should escape dynamic data being used in SQL queries; however, I'm just going to assume you've already sanitized both the `$cat_id` and `$post_id` values? (e.g. `$cat_id = absint( $_POST['cat_id'] )`)

Comment: Thank you. Of course everything is sanitized

Comment: That was just a gentle reminder.. So would you mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: That's an upvote, I was referring to the checkmark next to my answer which you can tick to mark the answer as "correct" - more details [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).